# How to get list and convert it to dataframe by web scraping in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scrapped data from a page in python. i am able to print content of table tag. But after that i am unable to get it as a list and convert it to dataframe. This is my code-

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
wiki = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/ships/all/per_page:50/page:1"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
#print soup.prettify()
print soup.title.string
#print soup.a

all_links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in all_links:
     link.get("href")
all_tables=soup.find_all('table')
right_table=soup.find('table', class_='table table-hover text-left')
print right_table
#Generate lists
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
E=[]
F=[]
G=[]
for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    states=row.findAll('img') #To store second column data
    if len(cells)==12: #Only extract table body not heading
          A.append(states[0].find(text=True))
          B.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
          C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
          D.append(cells[3].find(text=True))
          E.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
          F.append(states[1].find(text=True))
          G.append(cells[6].find(text=True))
df=pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['Flag'])
df['Vessel ID']=B
df['MMSI']=C
df['Vessel Name']=D
df['Photo']=E
df['Type']=F
df['Latest Position']=G
print df
```

it is only giving data of one field. rest fields are empty or giving none. 
Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: i want the data like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2hxT.png)
But i am getting output [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcsKZ.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want to do -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([A, B, C, D, E, F, G], columns=['Flag', 'Vessel ID', 'MMSI', 'Photo', 'Type', 'Latest Position'])
print df
```

Comment: What is the value of `df` you get with this code? And what do you want it to be? @AshishBaboo

Comment: It looks like a problem with scraping. Try printing arrays `A`, `B`, `C`,.. and check if the values are not empty.

Comment: if i print right_table . It is correctly displaying the whole data. So error is after that.

Comment: So what does `A` or `B` or `C` look like?

Comment: i am doing some thing wrong while generating the lists. Because when i print A , B or C they give me either none or 'u\n that is blank.